# Need ubuntu with old kernel ( < 2.6.31)?

Tags: apt, kernel

I have here some old applications and modules which ones only run on older linux kernels. I need an ubuntu with kernel < 2.6.31

I tought there are two options:
1.) Download 8.04/8.10 - there is an older kernel but I cannot use apt-get anymore to get stuff :/ I says its not supported
2.) Using 11.10 and change the kernel. But thats the question how? Is it even possible?

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: is your `processor` 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the previous kernel easily, but there is no assurance that all of your system will work as it should

For 32bit-Intrepid Ibex(8.10)

```
mkdir kernel&&cd ./kernel&&wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.30.10/linux-headers-2.6.30-02063010-generic_2.6.30-02063010_i386.deb&&wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.30.10/linux-image-2.6.30-02063010-generic_2.6.30-02063010_i386.deb&&sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

For 64bit-Intrepid Ibex(8.10)

```
mkdir kernel&&cd ./kernel&&wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.30.10/linux-image-2.6.30-02063010-generic_2.6.30-02063010_amd64.deb&&wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.30.10/linux-headers-2.6.30-02063010-generic_2.6.30-02063010_amd64.deb&&sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

You can then select the kernel at the grub screen...

Answer (score 0):

You can always a compile from kernel.org (http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.30.tar.xz)

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

In the wget command , you will need to execute `wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.30.tar.xz`

Also after finishing with `make menuconfig` you just need to type `make` (which should take time) and then `make install`